# How to route SQL print output to log file?

Tags: sql, powershell, invoke

Anyone who knows how to route `print ' '` in an sql script to a logfile when using `Invoke-Sqlcmd`?

I tried using `sqlcmd -o someoutfile.txt`, but it overwrites, it does not append to existing file. And if an SQL error occurs, only the error message is sent to file, not the `print ' '`.
When using `Invoke-Sqlcmd | out-file someoutfile.txt -Append`, it appends only `Write-Output` and eventually SQL errors, but not the `print ' '` in the sql script excuted.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting all output streams to the output file, in case the message is written to e.g. the verbose or debug stream? (`Invoke-Sqlcmd *>&1 | Out-File ...`)

Answer (score 4):

Invoke-SqlCmd implements T-SQL PRINT statements and RAISERROR using the verbose parameter. To capture verbose output, first you'll need to include the parameter in your call to invoke-sqlcmd i.e. **invoke-sqlcmd -verbose** and next you can do one of two things:

If you're using Powershell V3 or higher you can redirect verbose output:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -verbose 4>&1 | outfile someoutfile.txt
```

If you're using Powershell V2 you can't redirect verbose output to a file, however you can use start-transcript to send all screen output to a file. One gotcha with this approach--it will not work with SQL Agent Powershell job step. It will however work with a cmdexec job step which calls powershell.exe.

Comment: I am using Powershell v2, and verbose does not include the sql script print '', only the write-output in the powershell script. 
It seems like upgrading to v3 might solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And one moment...

The command "Invoke-Sqlcmd" has a parameter -SeverityLevel.
SeverityLevel specifies the lower limit for the error message severity level Invoke-Sqlcmd returns to the ERRORLEVEL PowerShell.

Invoke-Sqlcmd does not report severities for informational messages that have a severity of 10!

Severity Level 10: Status Information
This is an informational message that indicates a problem caused by mistakes in the information the user has entered. Severity level 0 is not visible in SQL Server.